# What other types are there for the jQuery promise object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been recently reading about the [`promise([type] [,target])`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/#promise-type-target) function that returns a [Promise](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise) object.

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/promise/#promise-type-target) states that the default `type` is `fx`:

> By default, `type` is "`fx`", which means the returned Promise is resolved when all animations of the selected elements have completed.

For some reason I'm having a hard time finding other available types. I assume that other types could be e.g. `ajax` which gets resolved when content is loaded into a collection using `load()` or similar methods (*note that I know how to handle `load()` promises, I'm just giving an example*).

Is there a list somewhere specifying all available types? I was thinking about [looking at the source code](http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/docs/05-queue.html) to find that out, however I was hoping there is a list somewhere, unless `fx` is the only sensible type one can use with this function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation says about the `type` argument:

> The type of queue that needs to be observed.

By default, all animation functions are added to the `fx` queue. But with [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), you can "attach" functions to selected elements which are run in order to a queue of your choice (which *you* can define).

So, the promise would get resolved once all functions in the specified queue have been called. Though I haven't seen this in practice yet.

Example:

```
$('div').queue('foo', [function(next) {
    setTimeout(next, 2000); // some delay
}, function(next) {
    console.log('Last function in queue');
    next();
}]).dequeue('foo');

$('div').promise('foo').done(function() {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PqmzG/)

Comment: Does this mean that there aren't any other "built-in" queue types? I guess only animations get queued up in that way really.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK `fx` is the only built-in queue.

Comment: Awesome, that's helpful. I'll wait for a bit before accepting your answer though, perhaps other people have encountered other examples. Thanks!